# How to filter list of enums with OData(7.4) .Net Core without specifying full namespace?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, odata

I am trying to filter list of enums with OData(7.4) in .Net Core Web Api (3.1) app with Entity Framework Core.  For example:

```
public class User 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Skill> Skills { get; set; }
}


public enum Skill
{
    Eating = 1,
    Breathing = 2,
    Walking = 3,
    Drinking =4
}
```

I am able to filter Users specifying the full namespace this way:
"UserApi.Domain.Models.CommonTypes.EnumTypes.Skill'Eating' in skills"
but in this way we receive too long URLs.
Is it possible to filter users by enums in this way or something like this:
"Skill'Eating' in skills" - without specifying full namespace?

Comment: An enum can be either cast to an integer of string.

Comment: I have tried such casts, they don't work for lists. Could you possibly provide an example, maybe I have tried other approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
           List<User> users = new List<User>() { 
                new User() { Id = new Guid("11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555"), Name = "John", Skills = new List<Skill>() { Skill.Breathing, Skill.Eating}},
                 new User() { Id = new Guid("11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555556"), Name = "Mary", Skills = new List<Skill>() { Skill.Drinking , Skill.Walking}},
                 new User() { Id = new Guid("11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555557"), Name = "Harry", Skills = new List<Skill>() { Skill.Eating, Skill.Drinking}},
                 new User() { Id = new Guid("11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555558"), Name = "Peter", Skills = new List<Skill>() { Skill.Walking , Skill.Breathing}}                                    
            };

            var skills = users.Select(x => new { name = x.Name, skills = string.Join(",",x.Skills.Select(y => y.ToString()))}).ToList();
```

Comment: I need to do it with Odata

Comment: OData model should have a list of users.  Code above can be used with any List<User>.